# AppEngine OpenAPI WebServlet and SecurityDefinitions Generation Support

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, openapi

AppEngine OpenAPI 2.0 doc was generated by following the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/get-started-frameworks-java#generating_the_openapi_configuration_file). However `WebServlet` method calls and `securityDefinitions` are not available as part of the generated doc.

Do I need to add the `WebServlet` and `securityDefinitions` manually or there is a configuration available to add that?

I had not got a reference to add `@ApiMethod` annotation to HttpServlet. Is there a reference sample available?

Comment: [In these GCP docs webpage](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/annotations#sample_apimethod_annotation) you have the @ApiMethod sample code. Also, this page lists all the available annotations.

Comment: `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse` are the input and output argument for HttpServlet call, say `doGet` or `doPost`. The parameters are referred and modified in the call, how to reflect the same in OpenAPI doc.